# Add id to the downloaded youtube playlist

Tags: linux, rename, youtube-dl

I've downloaded a youtube playlist with youtube-dl is there any way i can rename the files i've downloaded to the appended id of the file in playlist.

e.g. now

- xyz.mp4
- abc.mkv

want

- 1 - xyz.mp4
- 2 - abc.mkv

(which is according to the number in the youtube playlist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the files are sortable by date (check if the following produces the right output):

```
i=1; ls -1trd * | while read -r filename; do echo $i' - '"$filename"; i="$(( i + 1 ))"; done
```

Then this will rename them. ***NO UNDO FUNCTION FOR THIS***

```
i=1; ls -1trd * | while read -r filename; do mv -vb "$filename" $i' - '"$filename"; i="$(( i + 1 ))"; done
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. How did you do that? Can you provide me a link or a book to  do some stuff in whatever language you used (if not bash). Again Thanks

Comment: @MayankMittal That is bash, try reading https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Bash_Shell_Scripting, http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/, or even http://www.shelldorado.com/

Answer (score 0):

Use the command: youtube-dl --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --output "%(uploader)s%(title)s.%(ext)s" http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtOvBOTyX00

Comment: i can't do that it's a 200 videos of 1-2GB each and i've downloaded all of them.

Comment: And in the title there is no id otherwise it would've been in the file title